# Broken scene/world lighting on shader to rgb material?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, shader-nodes

I've been playing around while following a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEgzuMmJtu8) to make a material that makes use of the shader to rgb node, and somehow the lighting is now either completely black or washed out when I switch from shader preview to rendered view. I've replaced and fiddled with all the scene lights and world background to no avail. Is there any way to fix this?

Behavior using Shader-to-rgb material (broken):
[image: top-left: Shader preivew, bottom-right: scene render]

Behavior using Toon-shader material (expected):
[image: top-left: Shader preivew, bottom-right: scene render]

[Better demonstration with video](https://giant.gfycat.com/SlimyArcticHairstreak.mp4)

Nodes:
[image]

Comment: If you happen to be using Cycles you should know that the Shader to RGB node is an EEVEE exclusive feature. Additionally, the Toon shader is a Cycles exclusive feature.

Comment: @Avereniect Huh, well all screenshots were taken with EEVEE so I'm not sure what gives